# invalid_client in google oauth2

Tags: google-oauth, google-data-api, oauth2-playground

I try to make a web page for youtube video upload, therefore I try to get the client id from google api console, and in the api console it shows something like this:

```
Client ID: 533832195920.apps.googleusercontent.com
Redirect URIs: http://bobyouku.ap01.aws.af.cm/testyoutube.php
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
```

However when I try to test my account using the following URL:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=533832195920.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbobyouku.ap01.aws.af.cm%2Ftestyoutube.php&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&response_type=code&access_type=offline

It gives out the result of invalid_client. Even when I try it on oauth2 playground, same fail occurs

So anyone knows what's happen?

Comment: I found that sometimes the oauth2 client id doesn't work. I don't know why, but when I open a new account and create the client id again, it works.

Comment: Bob is right, creating the client id solves this problem

Comment: Make sure when copy/pasting the client id you don't include a trailing space. That did the trick for me...

Comment: for me, i regenerated client secret and use that it worked. Seems the api is still unstable.

Answer (score 116):

Set/change your product name, I had this issue until I created a product name as same as project name.

The product name can be set in the Consent screen section of the Google Developers Console for your project. Look under APIs & auth in the left navigation and select Consent screen.
You need also to set your email address in the box above the product name.

Comment: Thankyou!! I was getting error ""Error: invalid_client. The OAuth client was not found." Wasted several hours today on this, but updated the product name just now and hey-presto, problem fixed. That error is *so* misleading.

Comment: What is the product name?

Comment: It's in the consent screen. You have to fill out the 'PRODUCT NAME' field

Comment: This worked. Just to be succinct: set both 'PRODUCT NAME' **AND** 'EMAIL ADDRESS' fields.

Comment: That did not work for me. Is it the same name of the app installed and running on the device? I did that. No success!!!

Comment: Not working for me and no info provided to understand what causes the problem

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day! And I must say, out of all social providers Google has the worse docs and worst UI. It's so overwhelming and confusing along with their bad navigation. I almost always forget how to go to the project configuration page lol.

Comment: Such an arbitrary reason

Answer (score 76):

After copy values from Google web UI, I had a blank space for:

- `client_id`
- `secret`

And at the **BEGINNING** and at the **END** for both.

This happens even when clicking on the "copy" button.

Comment: This issue still persists :P

Comment: Unbelievable, even when clicking the "copy" button in the API console... You'd think Google's developers area would be whitespace sensitive!

Comment: Unbelievable as well here. Delete those extra spaces on both sides of the string. Then if after following all what has been said here and nothing still works, delete the app/project and re-create it again coz there could be caching issues.

Comment: Yeap, the issue still exists!!! Holy crap. I omitted one white space and didn't see it until recheck. Thanks.

Comment: darn! I saw the space at the end and removed it but did not check for the space in the beginning.

Comment: How come this hasn't been reported? Where the heck I report this stuff?!

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you SO much. I could have spent hours confused without realizing that I had an extra newline in my environment variable.

Answer (score 42):

Trim the leading and trailing white space from both the `client_id` and `client_secret`. Google's copy button does not do this for you.

[image]

Set both the email address and product name fields for the OAuth consent screen.

[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't leave your client secret exposed in an answer like that.

Comment: @Fernando It's a throw away account.

Comment: Phew. Had me worried there Shaun :D

Comment: How did you get to this screen?

Comment: "Throw away account" - not for Google, which tracks you and bundles all accounts you ever used to "associated accounts". And once Google bans one of the accounts - the whole bundle is blocked. Just search for "Google Developer account terminated" on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/).

Comment: Good call @AlexanderFarber... it is better safe than it is sorry especially when the fix is easy.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin You do realize your data is still visible in the answer editing history? Just FYI

Comment: Good to know. I appreciate that @Mark.

Answer (score 16):

Setting EMAIL ADDRESS and PRODUCT NAME in the consent screen of Google developer console, solves the error "Error: invalid_client. The OAuth client was not found." for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had .apps.googleusercontent.com twice in my ID.

It was a copy and paste issue "Your ID HERE".apps.googleusercontent.com

Comment: Mine was a blank space left on either end :/

Answer (score 8):

invalid_client can also simply means that your client ID and client secret are wrong when you create your Oauth2 object.

Answer (score 7):

in this thread i found my answer.

1. I went to google console,
2. generate a new project, made refresh, because in my case after create the page didn't reload
3. select new project
4. create a client ID
5. use it for what you need

thanks guys :D

Answer (score 6):

In my case this turned out to be something else, namely my code used an environment variable that hadn't been set properly (and stupidly wasnt checked by my code).  Setting it, recompiling assets, and restarting the app did the trick.

Comment: Same here; I had set it but forgot to restart my terminal

Comment: Updated my batch file from `set MY_ENV_VAR='a string'` to `set MY_ENV_VAR=a string`, and the error went away. The extraneous quote strings in the environmental variable were being parsed as part of the string itself.

Answer (score 6):

If you follow the documentation, from this page
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id

you'll see

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

But it's wrong. It should be

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID">
```

The issue is that the '.apps.googleusercontent.com' gets added anyway. If you do it like the documentation says, you get '.apps.googleusercontent.com' twice

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing it as you have suggested did the trick.

Comment: You are right! It worked as you stated.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by removing unnecessary quotes from my clientID and clientSecret values.

Comment: You sir/maam are a legend! I removed the quotes from my Heroku environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Did the error also report that it was missing an application name? I had this issue until I created a project name (e.g. "Project X") in the project settings dialog.

Answer (score 2):

probably old credentials are invalid

see the answer below

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41568247/7925598)

or short names may work

see the answer below
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029912/7925598)

or product name same as project name as answered already

at times one may include extra space in the

check twice this line so that you are redirected to the correct url

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with trim :

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' =>trim('client_id),
    'client_secret' => trim('client_secret'),
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/google/callback',
],
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the following were my issue - I resolved this by opening an incognito window. Something was obviously being cached somewhere, no amount of changing auth client settings helped and there were never any trailing or leading spaces in config values.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Project name on  Google APIs console.
you choose another project you created.
I was same error.
my mistake was choosing diffirent project.

Answer (score 0):

At Credentials 
Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) (Optional)
Use asterisks for wildcards. If you leave this blank, requests will be accepted from any referrer. Be sure to add referrers before using this key in production.
Add *.* (star dot star) . It work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally had a value in the Client Secret part of the URL, but Google Credential does not need a Client Secret for Android OAuth 2 Client IDs. Simply leaving the value blank in the URL did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that worked for me:

1. Delete credentials that are not working for you
2. Create new credentials with some NAME
3. Fill in the same NAME on your OAuth consent screen
4. Fill in the e-mail address on the OAuth consent screen

The name should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check:

When you install the GoogleAPIs into a .Net app with NuGet, it will inject a new set of dummy values in your *.config file.

Check that any original values are still in place, and remove dummy entries.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting client ID and creating new one a couple of times worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mine didn't work because I created it from a button from the documentation. I went again to the project and created another OAuthClientID. It worked. Yes, be careful about the extra spaces on right and left too.

Answer (score 0):

For best results make sure you have the complete details as follows:

```
{"client_id":"282324738-4labcgdsd4nlh34885s2d34tmi.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"abcd23ss-212808","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"23452-dfgdfgcdfgfd","redirect_uris":["http://localhost:6900/auth/google/callback"],"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:6900"]}
```

This data is always available for download as JSON from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Meteor JS, you have to use **clientId** instead **appId**:

Since facebook uses appId and google clientId.

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
    service: "google"
}, {
    $set: {
        clientId: process.env.OAUTH_GOOGLE_APP_ID,
        loginStyle: "popup",
        secret: process.env.OAUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET
    }
});
```

I spent some hours to realize over that.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had seen this post before, because there are a lot of things I had to find out trial and error. A lot can go wrong with this. Here's another issue I had:

Whe you specify the Authorised Javascript origins or Authorised redirect URIs, make sure to include your domain with and without www. So https://google.com and https://www.google.com

Also I had uploaded an Application logo. Because of that, the consent screen required a review... which takes forever. Don't upload an Application logo, or be very patient.

Answer (score 0):

this could also be because of not using `https` url.

In other words,this only works with `https`. It works with `http` only in `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to remove the `'` single quotes and remove additional spaces at the end of the client id and secret in the `.env` file