# invalid_client in jsonresponse in oauth2 android

Tags: java, android, json, oauth-2.0

I'm doing the oauth2 for google i'm able to getting the authorization code but i can't able to get the accesstoken from the authorization code.

i'm getting invalid json_response like

```
{

"error":"invalid_client"
}
```

I have tried with by updating the product name of the application. by this [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536089/2582340).
But it not helped.

Here is the code to obtain the get the AccessToken.
GetAccessToken

```
public class GetAccessToken {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
public GetAccessToken() {}
List < NameValuePair > params = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
Map < String, String > mapn;
DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
HttpPost httpPost;
public JSONObject gettoken(String address, String token, String client_id, String client_secret, String redirect_uri, String grant_type) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // DefaultHttpClient
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(address);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", token));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", redirect_uri));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grant_type));
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSONStr", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // Parse the String to a JSON Object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // Return JSON String
    return jObj;
}}
```

Code to parse the json_response.

**TokenGet.class**

```
 private class TokenGet extends AsyncTask < String, String, JSONObject > {
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     String Code;@
     Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Contacting Google ...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
         Code = pref.getString("Code", "");
         pDialog.show();
     }@
     Override
     protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...args) {
         GetAccessToken jParser = new GetAccessToken();
         JSONObject json = jParser.gettoken(TOKEN_URL, authCode, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, GRANT_TYPE);
         return json;
     }@
     Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         if (json != null) {
             try {
                 String tok = json.getString("access_token");
                 String expire = json.getString("expires_in");
                 String refresh = json.getString("refresh_token");
                 Log.d("json", json.toString());
                 Log.d("Token Access", tok);
                 Log.d("Expire", expire);
                 Log.d("Refresh", refresh);
                 auth.setText("Authenticated");
                 Access.setText("Access Token:" + tok + "\nExpires:" + expire + "\nRefresh Token:" + refresh);
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             pDialog.dismiss();
         }
     }
 }
```

Give Me,Any Suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i had some troubles like you using AsyncTask:

So, i recommend you to use VolleY, its very easy to do what you are doing with this library...

I think your problema is that you are not using the correct Charset... try adding this to your code:

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

if it doesnt work, lets me know...

If you are interested to use Volley lets me know.... i am not an expert, but i can help you, actually i am using this.