# invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, gcloud

Was trying to use [their Python API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary), however received this error:

> Failed to create bucket: invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found.

In case it was an issue with my configuration, I tried with the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), tested with: `gsutil du`

> Your "Oauth 2.0 User Account" credentials are invalid. Please run
>     $ gcloud auth login
>   Failure: invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found..

#### Troubleshooting

- I have run `gcloud auth login` and it succeeded.
- Tried creating a new project with same product-name and project-name, but that left me with same error

Comment: Let me know if this previous answer solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19536089/81491

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that but it didn't solve the problem. (see my second bullet-point in the troubleshooting section)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command `gcloud auth list` on cloud sdk, it will list the account you are using currently.

Make sure that the account is active and you used for creating the project should be same.

Please also go through [the document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CredentialTypesSupportingVariousUseCases). It gives you an idea of what and how you can use the credential

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have torn down your service accounts/recreated them and thus invalidated their permissions.

Comment: Ahem, this was debugging a problem I was having with a tool 4 years ago. One would imagine the interfaces have gone through thousands of iterations since.

Comment: I don't think the OAuth interface has changed since we were getting this error from gcloud yesterday and since OAuth is a standard that hasn't changed much (besides OpenId Connect). It's useful to know that service accounts + SDK clients are OAuth clients.

Comment: This was my issue: make sure your service account is still present. If it is and you're still getting the issue, download a new private key and try it again.