# Why am I still getting invalid_client error?

Tags: java, eclipse, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api

I am working on a Google Drive API [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java)

I am currently on the part where you run the demo. When I visit the [URL](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=37895131772&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) generated by the program, I get this error - "Error: invalid_client
. The OAuth client was not found."

Here is my code(subbed in my client_id and client_secret)

```
 public class DriveCommandLine {

  private static String CLIENT_ID = "37895131772";
  private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "laUVGRI53uXzT90Ag880HSkT";
  private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
 ....
```

I double checked the client_id and client_secret on the Developer's console to make sure those components were not the issue.(tutorial didn't say to replace redirect_uri)

Does anyone know what the issue is? I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2) as well and the solution there was to set email and product name to the same name as the Eclipse project. I did both(my email and  DriveTutorial, name of Eclipse project) but still I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct client ID (sorry for asking but read below)?

I just generated one and it looks like this:
826972360704-pc2l8e4bvvg7e4a64nen8ofdsk41c60p.apps.googleusercontent.com
Your client ID looks like it is just the first numbers before the dash (unless you obfuscated it which is usually not needed since client id is considered public information)

Also I tried calling following URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=897110948812-7nhm1mqpb8dekoalbl6go7appruttn01.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth2callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

And correctly got the OAuth "grant permission to application X" prompt.

Comment: I went to that url you posted and got an invalid parameter value error

Comment: Updated the answer with completely correct URL. I changed the redirect URI to match the client allowed redirect URIs