# 401. That’s an error. Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am working with Google Drive File Picker by following this [Google Drive File Picker Example](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054) demo project. I have generated API Key and Client Id. But when I run the project I am getting following error

> 401. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.

I have also checked [This Google Drive File Picker Example Link](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054) but it does not work, Please help me to solve my issue.

[invalid_client in google oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2).

[image]

Comment: Did you authorize with OAuth?

Comment: Yes i did, I have downloaded the demo project and got client id and api key from google console, but still it is not running.

Comment: open Request details in that image

Comment: added image of request detail.

Comment: Did you enable Drive SDK on your project?

Answer (score 27):

Your `client_id` is not correct, re-check pls

Comment: client_id seems to include a carriage-return

Comment: It works for me thnks

Answer (score 8):

In my case, i mistakenly add a `,` in the values in my `.env` files so better check that file

```
# check the comma at the end
AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=randomauthsecret,
AUTH_CLIENT_ID=randomclientid,
```

That causes the wrong client id value. So just remove the `,`. Another thing, also don't enclose them in quotes.

```
AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=randomauthsecret
AUTH_CLIENT_ID=randomclientid
```

Comment: Yeah in my case, I entered client_id where api_key was supposed to be and vice versa and I wasted my 20 minutes. Thanks for saving me some time.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

In the following pic, I made with restricted mode in API keys section. This helped me to to remove the display. Hence finally, shown as:

```
No API keys to display
```

Try to validate the client_id with those that you created for your project as:

https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/credentials?folder=&organizationId=&project=saml-281612

The project name, like in my case, it is **saml**, should match with the project apps as **saml** to mitigate mismatch_uri error.

This helped me to remove all those errors as:

```
1. Error 400 : mismatch_uri
2. Error 401 : invalid client_id
```

Answer (score 4):

you may be getting this error if you are already logged in to a google account on your system so log out of all accounts and then run the code

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after I removed the quotation marks I had set in my environment variable

Answer (score 2):

The problem was how vscode format the code, it leaves spaces within the client_id, so I used atom to write the client_id in the .env file and ran app.js through hyper. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Also facing the same issue and wasted half an hour, the thing that worked for me was creating a new credential and replacing old credential in code with new.

And then it was working as expected

Comment: Brevity is great, but only when brevity is able to achieve a clear and concise answer. This answer lacks any sort of explanation &/or example.

Answer (score 1):

May be values are not correct in .env file for "Client ID" and "Client secret" or mistake of using "," in file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue sometimes back what helped was adding a space when passing the client id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was my problem: VS 2022 * performs autoformatting when pasting into code outside "". Part of this formatting is to separate "-" from other characters with space.

Answer (score 0):

check if there is a semi-colon or comma at the end of your dotenv(.dotnv) file

AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=randomauthsecret;
AUTH_CLIENT_ID=randomclientid,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have written client_id in GOOGLE_SECRET and client_secret in GOOGLE_ID, that's why it was not working,

Please recheck your env file

Just a ultimate solution, delete old credentials, and create new

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with this, what happened with mine was that I put my clientId and secret key in a string. When I removed the string, it worked perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but i fixed it with this
if you forget to add .env file or .env.local when you clone you should have to add this  manually
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ="your client id"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="your cleint secret"