# Getting `The OAuth client was not found.` and `invalid client` error when trying to get access token for google cloud logging services in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, jwt

I'm following through this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest_1 in order to have my flutter app log to a log bucket in a google cloud project. Currently getting a

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "The OAuth client was not found."
}
```

when I run the code below to get the access token in dart:

```
  var jsonFile =
      await File(jsonPath).readAsString();
  var map = jsonDecode(jsonFile);

  final jwt = JWT(
    {
      'iss': map['client_email'],
      'sub': map['client_email'],
      'aud': map['token_uri'],
      'iat': (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).floor(),
      'exp':
          (DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 1)).millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000)
              .floor(),
    },
    issuer: map['private_key_id'],
  );

  final token = jwt.sign(SecretKey(map['private_key']));

  print(token);

  final accessToken = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(map['token_uri']),
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
      'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'assertion': token,
    },
  );
```

The JSON file is the credentials of a service account with logging admin role in the GCP project.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid client means that the client id or the client secret that you are using are not valid.

As per the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/authorization#invalid_client),

> When attempting to get an access or refresh token, you will get an
> "Invalid client" error if you provide an incorrect OAuth 2.0 Client
> Secret. Make sure the client_secret value you're using in access and
> refresh token calls is the one for the OAuth 2.0 Client ID being used,
> as found in your [GCP Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

Also refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205824/401-that-s-an-error-error-invalid-client-the-oauth-client-was-not-found)  Github [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/211) for more information.