# Error : invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: google-oauth

I tried to get the client id from google api console.
But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

Request Details
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email
    response_type=code
    redirect_uri={{ url }}
    client_id=O
```

I have seen the following answers but none of them worked for me:
[ClickToSee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2/19536089#19536089)

Comment: which type of oauth client did you make?

Comment: I have used OAuth 2.0

Comment: I've been having this problem with Google Oauth for the past 24 hours.  There was also an issue with many error messages popping up in the developer console in the credentials area.  I think creating new Google Oauth credentials is broken right now.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried again this morning and creation of new Oauth 2 credentials is working now.  Seems to have been down for a day.