# I am stuck with a "401. That's an error Error: invalid_client"

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have take the code from http://hayageek.com/login-with-google-plus-javascript-api/

I have implemented the code with my client_id, api key and  also followed the instructions of [invalid_client in google oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2)
but still I get the same error.

Also in the OAuth Consent Screen and mention the product name and email address

> 401. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_client
>
> Application: Project_Name
>
> You can email the developer of this application at: email_address
>
> no registered origin

Comment: Go to google developers console under your Oauth2 credentials make sure you have supplied javascript origin

Comment: Please tell me what can I write in the Javascript origin URL. What type of URL I have to write in that field.. Thanks in advance

Comment: you might want to try reading Googles tutorial https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/javascript#step_1_enable_the_google_api

Comment: I am running application in the node-webkit, so what is the url of Javascript origin as I gone through all sites, login button works online only.Whenever I implement the code, no output is there and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the Authorized JavaScript origins url along with the Authorized redirect URIs while creating the Oauth credentils for your project.