# invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found. Python

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I have an old project, that is trying to retrieve data from google analytics.

It is not working, so I am trying to figure out what's wrong.

Found an example code to work with Analytics on server side.

```
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
  key_file_location = 'secrets.json'

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_file_location, scopes=scope)
  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
  service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()
  print (accounts)
```

It is working with secrets file for my test account.
But it's not working for secrets file of an old project.
I recieve the following error:

```
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found.
```

What's the problem? The secrets file is out of date? If it is, am I able to recieve another one without access to the google account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you registered the application on Google developer console you created some OAuth credentials.

> invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found

means that the client id you are using isn't there anymore someone probably deleted it.  You will need to create new credentials.

Comment: So I have two options, as I understood.
1. Retrieve access to an account, where this Client_ID was created and create another "service account keys".
2. Create Client_ID on another account. Give permissions in Google Analytics from accounts with Analytics installed to this account.

Am I wright?

Comment: exactly however it sounds to me like who ever had access to the account that created your original client id service account keys has deleted it.    I would just create a new one and add permissions for it in Google analytics (option 2)