# ASP.NET Core 2 Google OAuth token endpoint failure

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem that relates to the authentication with the google. 
I followed the tutorials and finally managed to reach google site where I can select the choose an account section. Then I select one and get redirect to the local address: https://localhost:44377/signin-google?state ...

but there I get:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: Unauthorized;Headers: Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
Date: Sat, 10 Feb 2018 22:14:21 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Server: GSE
Vary: X-Origin, Origin, Accept-Encoding
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
;Body: {
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
;

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()
```

Any help in investigating this would be very helpful.

Comment: `"error": "invalid_client"`

Comment: Thank you - in my case there was a magic trailing space in the secret. I followed 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2. Now I can authenticate.